# Vanet cognitive radio simulation - do i need mixim?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo, mixim

I am implementing spectrum sensing for VANETs using SuMO, OMNeT++ and Veins. With these three, I believe I can simulate traffic scenarios. Is it also possible to perform spectrum sensing within the nodes (secondary users in VANETs) with only those 3 software packages or do I need to install MIXIM for cognitive radios as well?

Thanks,

Rop

Comment: It seems like you did not do research on MIXIM and cognitive radio before asking this question.

BTW: Veins contains MIXIM but only until version 2.1.

Comment: Update: It is version 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You ask "is it possible" and you mentioned C++ libraries containing simulation models. This makes the question somewhat hard to answer. Yes, the libraries you mention can support you to write a simulation that does what you described.

If your question is whether any of the libraries already contains code that implements the functionality you describe, the answer is no. You need to write that part yourself.